# MyBatis: invalid comparison: java.util.Date and java.lang.String

Tags: mybatis

I have a issues as below while comparing date in MyBatis as below

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid comparison: java.util.Date and java.lang.String

Both of java 'applyDate' and Postgres 'org_info.apply_date' type are Date

Here is my configuration:

```
<sql id="searchCriteriaSql">
    <where>enter code here
        <if test="applyDate != null &amp;&amp; applyDate != '' ">
            <![CDATA[org_info.apply_date &lt;= #{applyDate}]]>
        </if>
        <if test="ogrNm != null &amp;&amp; ogrNm != '' ">
            <bind name="ogrNmKey"
                value="'%' + ogrNm + '%'" />
            AND ( upper(org_info.org_nm) LIKE upper(#{ogrNmKey}))
        </if>
    </where>
</sql>
```

The root cause comes from

```
<![CDATA[org_info.apply_date &lt;= #{applyDate}]]>
```

Comment: Parse the string as a date first.

Comment: It's actually caused by the test condition `applyDate != ''`. As `applyDate` is `java.util.Date`, you should just write `<if test="applyDate != null">`.

Comment: Thank you so much.
That's works right !

Answer (score 0):

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid

comparison: java.util.Date and java.lang.String

#### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid comparison: java.util.Date and java.lang.String

```
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:97) ~[mybatis-spring-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:439) ~[mybatis-spring-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.selectOne(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

---

```
    <if test="fromDate!=null and fromDate!=''">
        AND a.punch_date &gt;= #{fromDate}
    </if>
    <if test="toDate!=null and toDate!=''">
        AND a.punch_date &lt;= #{toDate}
    </if>
```

For resolved this above issue, query syntax need to change.

enter code here

```
<if test="fromDate != null">
            AND a.punch_date &gt;= #{fromDate}
        </if>
        <if test="toDate != null">
            AND a.punch_date &lt;= #{toDate}
        </if>
```